# Is Android Emulator able to connect to a printer on PC as an On-The-Go Printer?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, usb-otg

I need to debug an Android application on either a physical Android Tablet or on an emulated AVD. The Android application needs to either connect to a USB printer using the Tablet's On-The-Go port or somehow have the printer appear to the emulator as connected to an AVD's On-The-Go port. There are two problems with the setup.

1. In order to debug the application on the Tablet I need to use the same USB port as a PC client while simultaneously using the port as an On-The-Go port for the printer. Any ideas on how to achieve this?
2. If I emulate the application in an AVD, how can I simulate an On-The-Go connection in the emulator so I can have a real connection to the USB printer?